# proper jquery syntax for setting element's content

Tags: jquery

how can I convert the following to JQuery syntax?

```
selectedelement.innerHTML="some html code";
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
for selectedelement is a id
$('#selectedelement').html('some html code');
for selectedelement is a class
$('.selectedelement').html('some html code');
for selectedelement is a name
$('[name="selectedelement"]').html('some html code');
```

Comment: @user3260061 If `selectedelement` is an object than the example in your question won't work at all.